# How to attach the source to the jar in the Gradle (Gradle 6.3.) build that can be used in eclipse External Dependencies

Tags: java, gradle

Problem: I have a gradle project in which I am using let's say 'pocdemo.jar' as gradle dependency. When I try to navigate through the method call hierarchy, it doesn't show the actual code, instead it shows something like shown in image below
[image]

I want to have the source attached for the external dependency, I tried to do that by selecting the jar -> properties -> Java Source Attachment, but that didn't allow me to add the location for the source. Now I want to know is there a way that I can use in build.gradle file that will include the source during the jar creation itself.
I have the below gradle file for the project that I use as external dependency in my main project.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
  maven {
            url = repoUrl
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
            metadataSources { 
                mavenPom()
                artifact() 
            }
        }
    maven {
            url = biappsUrl
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
            metadataSources { 
                mavenPom()
                artifact() 
            }
        }
  }
    dependencies {
        classpath(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-gradle-plugin', version: '2.1.3.RELEASE')
    }
}

apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
apply plugin:'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'


configurations.all {
   exclude group: "commons-logging", module: "commons-logging"
   exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-tomcat"
}
configurations {
    javadocJar
}
dependencies {
   implementation(group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '3.1.0')
   implementation (group: 'org.springframework.retry', name: 'spring-retry')
   implementation(group: 'com.google.guava', name: 'guava', version: '27.0.1-jre')
   implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-web')
   implementation(group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-actuator')
   implementation group: 'commons-io', name: 'commons-io', version: '2.5'
   implementation group: 'commons-httpclient', name: 'commons-httpclient', version: '3.1'
   implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpmime', version: '4.1'
   implementation group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.2'
   implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5'
   implementation group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpcore', version: '4.4.1'
    .
    . <Some more dependencies>
    .
    testImplementation(group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-api-mockito2', version: '2.0.0-beta.5')
    testImplementation(group: 'org.mockito', name: 'mockito-core', version: '2.19.0')
    testImplementation(group: 'org.powermock', name: 'powermock-module-junit4', version: '2.0.0-beta.5')
}

javadoc {
  source = sourceSets.main.allJava
  classpath = sourceSets.main.compileClasspath
  destinationDir = file("${buildDir}/docs/javadoc")
  failOnError = true
}

task javadocJar (type: Jar, dependsOn: javadoc){
    from javadoc.destinationDir
    archiveFileName = "myapps-pco-demo-doc-${version}.jar"
}
jar {
    bootJar.enabled = false
    jar.enabled = true
    dependsOn 'javadocJar'
  archiveFileName = provider {
        'pocdemo.jar'
    }
    enabled = true
    manifest{
        attributes('Sealed': 'true')
    }
}


/* Eclipse config */
eclipse {
    classpath {
        downloadSources = true
        downloadJavadoc = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue too when using Spring Tool Suite, and I spent a lot of time investigating but cannot find any solutions.
But when I use Intellij, it works fine, I can go into the class file and debug it. So please try it with Intellij.